# ASP.NET Core routing empty parameters

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have controller with one method. 
Routing covers next scenarious:

```
1. userId="1" ,userEmail=null https://localhost:44371/api/customers/1
1. userId="1" ,userEmail="1" https://localhost:44371/api/customers/1/1
```

The main question how to send request when `userId=null`, `userEmail="1"`.
Use `%20` and request something like `https://localhost:44371/api/customers/%20/1`?
What is right way?

```
[HttpGet("{userId}")]
[HttpGet("{userId}/{userEmail}")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
{
    public JsonResult GetCustomer(string userId, string userEmail)
    {
        return new JsonResult(string.Format("userId: {0}, email: {1} ", userId, userEmail));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are routing in wrong way so change your code to this because you will need to routing in the action method

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{userId}/{userEmail}")]
    public JsonResult GetCustomer(string userId, string userEmail)
    {
        return new JsonResult(string.Format("userId: {0}, email: {1} ", userId, userEmail));
    }
}
```

So you can request api like this

```
https://localhost:44371/api/customers/1
```

Another example

```cs
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet] // Matches '/Products/List'
    public IActionResult List() {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")] // Matches '/Products/Edit/{id}'
    public IActionResult Edit(int id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```